# How can I log how long each ASP.NET WebAPI call takes?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is there a way to attack some sort of global logger so that I know how long each WebAPI request took?

Comment: I don't think you can track identify(match) a request with a response with a generic solution.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check out [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/).

It's got a lot of different adapters too- for example, I've used it with ServiceStack / Dapper, but it also works with MS vanilla WebApi / EF.

On localhost (or whatever criteria you use to turn the profiler on in your global app class), when you hit your site url's in the browser, you'll get a ui widget in the top right corner detailing total request time, serialization time, and database execution time (including the actual sql executed).

To view the last 100 requests, browse:
`~/mini-profiler-resources/results`

For more robust storage there are options [here](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/tree/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage) - sql server is supported out of the box.  Use this [create script](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/StackExchange.Profiling/Storage/SqlServerStorage.cs#L380) and then set the storage provider for MiniProfiler:

```
MiniProfiler.Settings.Storage = new SqlServerStorage("..connectionstring...");
```

Or [use Sqlite](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/Sample.Mvc/Helpers/SqliteMiniProfilerStorage.cs#L39) out of the box

You can even set multiple storage options.
[Examples here](https://github.com/MiniProfiler/dotnet/blob/master/Sample.Mvc/Global.asax.cs#L120)

When adding the profiler ui to view requests, it should look something like this
[image]